# How can i interpret a time value in ascii into a numerical value?

Tags: matlab

I have a file which is as follows:

15:03:21   II   0.88   0.64
15:03:31   II   0.88   0.64
15:03:42   II   0.40   0.40
etc.

after loading the file in matlab, I want to be able to read the first column (which corresponds to time) and interpret them as numerical values. At the moment, they are interpreted as a string of ascii characters and i can't perform any mathematical operations on them. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how i can read the time as numbers instead of a string of ascii characters?

Answer (score 6):

Use [DATENUM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html) and [DATEVEC](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/datevec.html) to convert your date strings to useful numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

Like Jonas said, but more specifically,

```
t = {'15:03:21 ' '15:03:31 ' '15:03:42 '};
datenum(t, 'HH:MM:SS')
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above answers there is another useful function [DATEVEC](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/datevec.html) which converts either date string or datenum output to vector of year-month-day-hours-minutes-seconds. Try it out:

```
tvec = datevec(t)
```

Notice that if there is only time in the string, the date will be January 1st of the current year. You can always cut it out with

```
tvec(:,1:3) = [];
```